# What is the fastest way to copy a double[] in Java?

Tags: java

Simple question, what's the fastest way of copying an array of doubles in Java.  I currently do this...

```
public static double[] clone_doubles(double[] from)
{
    double[] to = new double[from.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < from.length; i++) to[i] = from[i];
    return to;
}
```

which also does the allocation to avoid overflows, but if there is a quicker way I will separate the allocation from the copy.

I have looked at `Arrays.copyOf()` and `System.arraycopy()` but I'm wondering if anyone has any neat tricks.

**Edit:**
How about copying a `double[][]`?

Comment: What do you mean by "separate the allocation from the copy"? Do you mean that you are able to re-use destination arrays instead of allocating a new one? I'd guess that `System.arraycopy()` is fastest, much faster than your code. Have you profiled it?

Comment: Why not add `arr.clone()` to your list, benchmark all four methods, and post the results here? :-)

Comment: @aix, clone() is the same as Arrays.copy when JIT'd

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Java Practices did a comparison of different copy methods on arrays of `int`](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=3):

Here are the results from their site:

> java -cp . -Xint ArrayCopier performance 250000
>
> Using clone: 93 ms 
> Using System.arraycopy: 110 ms 
> Using Arrays.copyOf: 187 ms 
> Using for loop: 422 ms

Looks to me like a tie between `System.arraycopy()` and `clone()`.

Comment: interesting, the same site says avoid clone... http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=71

Comment: This is the kind of answer I like to see! :)

Comment: Since `clone()` does a shallow copy, there is a risk of references in your new array pointing back to things belonging to objects in your old array. As it says this isn't a risk for 1 dimensional primitive arrays like the one in your example.

Comment: @Simon the site says "avoid implementing clone" but not to avoid clone

Comment: Why there is so difference between System.arraycopy() (110 ms) and Arrays.copyOf() (187 ms) ? Is not Arrays.copyOf() uses System.arraycopy() internally ?

Comment: Their benchmark is significantly flawed. I would not trust their results (which BTW I know are inaccurate).

Comment: @Kailash Definitely, the results make no sense.

Answer (score 7):

[`System.arraycopy`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29) is probably your best bet if you just want to copy from one array to another.

Otherwise

```
public static double[] clone_doubles(double[] from) {
  return (double[]) from.clone();
}
```

will give you a clone.

Answer (score 1):

System.arraycopy() is your best bet. Generally, it's implemented with native instructions, probably involving direct calls to the operating system's memory manager.

In Java 6 the performance of arraycopy was [improved](http://192.9.162.55/performance/reference/whitepapers/6_performance.html#2.1.5) as "hand-coded assembly stubs are now used for each type size when no overlap occurs".

Read this other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2772152/why-is-system-arraycopy-native-in-java) for further details.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays.copy, [].clone and System.arraycopy w/ new object are using the same code path when properly JIT.

Here is the corresponding bug: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6428387

Answer (score 0):

```
public static double[] clone_doubles(double[] from)
{
    return Arrays.copyOf(from, from.length);
}
```

This is internally implemented using `System.arrayCopy()`:

```
public static double[] copyOf(double[] original, int newLength) {
    double[] copy = new double[newLength];
    System.arraycopy(original, 0, copy, 0,
                     Math.min(original.length, newLength));
    return copy;
}
```

Comment: this is irrelevant actually, it uses intrinsics, the code is not executed by the JIT like that