# What is the run time of String.toCharArray()?

Tags: java, string, copy, runtime, system

What's the run time of `String.toCharArray()` in java? The source code is

```
 public char[] toCharArray() {
    // Cannot use Arrays.copyOf because of class initialization order issues
    char result[] = new char[value.length];
    System.arraycopy(value, 0, result, 0, value.length);
    return result;
}
```

Does `System.arrayCopy`? have run time of O(n)? The source code doesn't really say much about how it's implemented. Does it go through every element and copies it? Thanks.

Comment: I am very sure runtime is **O(n)** it can't be better (the characters have to be copied). Question is what is the factor.

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11208577/485971

Comment: @irrelephant So it's probably **O(1)**? Since it's not iterating through a loop but copying a memory block?

Comment: Not really - I think it's still O(N) but with a low constant factor, as @MrSmith42 says. Sometimes it may have a higher constant factor - see http://stackoverflow.com/a/2589962/485971

Comment: Offtopic question, maybe but -- why do you care?

Comment: @fge for an algorithm that returns some info about the input strings or compare multiple strings, I can't achieve it in less than O(n) time if using `String.toCharArray()`. But a lot of times, it's easier to work w/ the string if it's converted to an array.

Comment: @cinnamontoast: Even if the method is copying *blocks* of memory, it still can't be `O(1)`. I would say, the run-time is still `O(N)`, where `N` is the number of blocks. Granted this is a faster approach, you still have to copy all of the blocks.

Answer (score 6):

`System.arraycopy()` is typically an intrinsic and is very fast. That said, it still has to look at (and copy) every element of the array, so its asymptotic complexity is linear in the length of the array, i.e. `O(n)`.

Thus the complexity of `toCharArray()` is `O(n)`, where `n` is the length of the string.