# faster way to assign static values to first 10 places in array

Tags: java, arrays

I want to assign integers 1-10 to already existing integer array first 10 values (index 0-9).  Is there way to do this quickly without for loop or do I need for loop?

Example:

```
//already existing array with index 0-14.
//want to change this to {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,1,1,1,1}
int[] array = {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1);
```

What I know:

```
int x = 1;
for (int a = 0; a < 10; a++)
{
    array[a] = x;
    x++;
}
```

Is there faster way, some command perhaps?

Thanks!

Comment: *"Is there faster way,"*  99% of the time, code clarity is more important than speed.  If the app. begins to bog down, check it using a profiler to check exactly where the bottleneck is.  The results are usually surprising.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could statically assign it, it is cleaner if you have static data

```
int[] array = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
```

Comment: @JohnSmith use another variable name something like myarray

Comment: John, I am not completely following you, if you want to create fixed size array with default value initialized (1...10), follow my answer, if you want to edit those value you still can edit by assigning value to array index like `arr[i] = someValue;`

Comment: for declaration time initialization you should prefer the way I suggested if the initial values are static, if you want to change it later you could still use loop, it depends on how long your array is, for 10 sized array it will not make much difference

Comment: `System.arrayCopy()` [is absolutely better , it uses `memcopy`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2772152/why-is-system-arraycopy-native-in-java), but you could copy array to another one, so it really depends if you have the array available which is going to be copied, Please read javadoc for it to troubleshoot why it is not working

Comment: Hi John, Your this behavior is SPAM considering SO's scope, Please follow guidelines you were given while registering account and you would be good

Answer (score 2):

You can create a static constant array of ten elements, and then copy it in place with System.arrayCopy.

```
static int[] template = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5,6 7,8,9,10};

System.arrayCopy(template, 0, dest, 0, 10);
```

The remaining elements of the dest array will remain intact.